# Vuex, changing state in an action

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to code as "good practice" as possible while learning Vuex.

From what I learning I tought that **Actions** are used to do for example external API calls, the result of that is passed to a **Mutation** via a commit().

> Now I want to increment a counter for a certain user on Firebase. This is working when I code my action like this

```
    ADD_CREDIT(context, user) {

        user.credits++;

        firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.id)
            .update({credits: user.credits})
            .then(() => {});

    }
```

So in my action I already update the state before calling the API call. Is this good practice? I tried it the other way using the following code, but that just looks to complicated.. And it doesn't work for now.

*Action*

```
ADD_CREDIT({commit, state}, user) {

        const newcredits = user.credits + 1;

        firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.id)
            .update({credits: newcredits})
            .then(() => {
                commit('CREDIT_CHANGED', user.id, newcredits)
            });

    }
```

*Mutation*

```
CREDIT_CHANGED(state, userid, newcredits) {
        let user = state.users.find(user => {
            return user.id = userid
        });

        user.credits = newcredits;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern of a mutation function is

```
function mutation(state, payload) {
...
// do something with state
state.person = payload;
...
}
```

It doesn't have anymore argument than that 2.

So, your mutations should pass an object with all of your information. Like this:

```
CREDIT_CHANGED(state, payload) {
   let user = state.users.find(user => user.id === payload.userid);
   user.credits = payload.newcredits;
}
```

And then you action should commit like this:

```
ADD_CREDIT({commit, state}, user) {

    const newcredits = user.credits + 1;

    firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.id)
        .update({credits: newcredits})
        .then(() => {
            commit('CREDIT_CHANGED', {
                 userid: user.id, 
                 newcredits: newcredits 
            })
        });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the whole point! Perfect answer.